# Set-AzureSubscription : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DefaultSubscription'

Tags: azure, powershell-2.0

I am setting azure subscription in powershell with "Set-AzureSubscription –DefaultSubscription $SubscriptionID" API.

But it is giving me error as "Set-AzureSubscription : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DefaultSubscription'."

Please guide me on if there is change in azure powershell API's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there was a change in the PowerShell APIs in a recent update.  The Select-AzureSubscription now has the parameter to set the default.  The name of that parameter is -Default (instead of -DefaultSubscription).

Comment: Can anyone please tell me if there are any change for "Start-AzureVM" API? 
It is getting struck with following command
"Start-AzureVM  -ServiceName (get-azurevm | where {$_.name -eq $VMName}).ServiceName  -NAME $VMName"

Answer (score 3):

As of version 0.7.2, you need to call Select-AzureSubscription with the subscription name, like this:

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "mySubscriptionName"
```

You can check what version of Azure cmdlets you have by running this command:

```
get-module azure
```

Which returns a result like this:

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Binary     0.7.2      Azure                               {Add-AzureAccount, Add-AzureCacheWorkerRole, Add-AzureCertificate, Add-AzureDataDisk...}